# Huge Temp table going on disk In mysql

Tags: mysql

How to avoid temporary table creation on disk in mysql if table has multiple text column.

I have given `tmp_table_size` to 1 GB and `Max_heap_size` = GB

Still tables going on Disk.

```
+-------------------------+-------+
| Variable_name           | Value |
+-------------------------+-------+
| Created_tmp_disk_tables | 70742 |
| Created_tmp_files       | 6     |
| Created_tmp_tables      | 71076 |
```

Thanks :-)

Comment: By not running the query or queries that are generating the tables.  Really, you don't provide any information for solving this problem.  You need to edit the question and describe something about your database and the queries you are running.